# Read from Firebase/Google Cloud Storage as a Buffer in Node.js function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I am using Node.js 8 version of Firebase functions and would like to retrieve a file from Google Cloud Storage to the function as a `Buffer`.

This seems straightforward:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const getRawBody = require('raw-body')

async function myFunction (path) {
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
  const file = await bucket.file(path).get()
  console.log("All good so far.")
  const buffer = await getRawBody(file.createReadStream()) // often fails.
}
```

The file I'm reading is trivially small (130kb).

This *did* work for a while, but now consistently fails with either a memory limit error or a timeout error, suggesting a Firebase/GCS issue.

I am aware I could increase the memory limit for the function, but if it failing on a trivially small file suggests grander problems at work and that it'll invariably fail on larger files.

Is there a better way to convert a GCS file to a `Buffer`?

If not, is the issue one that can be worked around?

Comment: I think with `const buffer = getRawBody(file.createReadStream())` you are mixing async and sync functions. so it should be `const buffer = await getRawBody(file.createReadStream())` because `raw-body` returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks @lependu; that is correct. I had originally written the example to return the call; will fix.  Of course this omission would lead to a short-circuit so doesn’t solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not apparently a Google Storage one, but rather the usage of the data elsewhere caused a memory overflow.

As a result, the `console.log` statements were not being recorded to the functions log, conflating the cause.

Answer (score 1):

Worked for me when I removed `get()` from `const file = await bucket.file(path).get()`

My working code is:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const getRawBody = require('raw-body')

async function getStream (path) {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
    const file = await bucket.file(path)
    const buffer = await getRawBody(file.createReadStream()) 
}
```