# fs.createReadStream() for Firebase remote file in Node

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, ipfs

I am working with the [Pinata Cloud SDK](https://github.com/PinataCloud/Pinata-SDK) specifically the `pinFileToIPFS` endpoint to upload a file to IPFS however I can't seem to generate a readableStream of my remote file in firebase storage.

Ideally I would be able to do something like this:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const readableStreamForFile = fs.createReadStream(FIREBASE_STORAGE_DOWNLOAD_URL_HERE);
```

However my backend throws an error when I attempt to do so. What's the best way to createReadStream for files submitted through my frontend?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `@google-cloud/storage` and `raw-body` packages to get it working, as recommended by [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53082711/read-from-firebase-google-cloud-storage-as-a-buffer-in-node-js-function/67830268#67830268)

Here's my working code to generate a readable stream (buffer in this case):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const getRawBody = require('raw-body')
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');


async function getStream (path) {
    const bucket = admin.storage().bucket()
    const file = await bucket.file(path)
    const buffer = await getRawBody(file.createReadStream()) 
}

await getStream()
```

Comment: based on code you don't use `Storage` from `const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');`